# point domain to my VPS CentOS7; Do I need DNS on my server?

Tags: centos, dns, domain, vps

I actually know how to configure my vps Virtual Host `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf` but my question is, do I have to setup any sort of DNS on my VPS?

Which way is the easiest way to point my domain to my server?

I read some articles but I couldn't find out, Do I need do anything (beside configuring my virtual host) on my VPS?

on my server I don't have Cpanel or anything like that and actually I just install LAMP stack on it, my domain is in ORG.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, so any suggestion??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is slanted into orienting the OP more into political problems than technical problems.

Comment: You are welcome; I myself was an expat almost 10 years in a 3rd world country working in the ISP business, and I am quite familiar with the technical, political difficulties and procedures on the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP has told me the domain, it is a .org (gov / NGO ) and it is not yet working (e.g. not yet configured but already registered).

The domain will have to be configured in a DNS server. No, I won't recommend registering it in the same VPS as your WEB server, it is not good practice.

The WHOIS also seems to state no name servers can be moved, so it must have some way of registering there the new domain/name, either by opening a ticket with someone, and giving them the data (for instance www.yourdomain.org and your VPS IP), or they will guide you registering that in a web interface, and possibly pointing to a DNS server (either yours, or from some other organisation)

You will have to talk with the people that sold/gave you the domain and clarify the procedures.

Obviously on your side, you need at least to define the name of the vhost in Apache.

Comment: but still I have one question do I need do anything on VPS, because I read somewhere in internet  that we could setup a DNS on our server but actually I don't like doing it. it takes my time and I'm not expert in this. So which is the easiset way ???

Comment: The DNS has to exist...try to find another gov organisation tied to you that runs a DNS and ask them or your ISP to register the domain on their servers, and they will point www.yourdomain.gov to your VPS IP address. First and foremost, ask advice from the guys that sold/gave you your domain, they will know better than us the situation on the field and how to get around that. Most gov local DNS agencies even give free training.